# Trying to get first character from a string with multiple words where the first can be an Emoji (Android)

Tags: java, android, string, substring

I need to get the first character of a string, currently what I'm using is:

```
String firstCharacter = getTitle().substring(0, 1);
```

where `getTitle()` returns a `String` that can contain multiple words and also emojis, if the first character is an emoji and I use `substring` when I display firstCharacter instead of the emoji I get a question mark because using `substring` I cut the emoji characters.

What I want to do is:

- if the first word is an emoji retrieve and assign it to `firstCharacter` without using `substring`;
- if the first word is an actual word use the `substring` as I'm currently doing;

How can I possibly do it?

Comment: have you tried using regex to check if first char is letter a-z or A-Z

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Android now supports Emojis with EmojiCompat

[EmojiCompat](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/text/emoji/EmojiCompat) is used to support Emojis in Android. You can initialize it by downloading it or packaging it within your app.

```
// Initialize with your desired config 
EmojiCompat.init(BundledEmojiCompatConfig(context))

// Check if EmojiCompat was successfully loaded
if (EmojiCompat.get().loadState == EmojiCompat.LOAD_STATE_SUCCEEDED) {
    EmojiCompat.get().hasEmojiGlyph(yourString)
}
```

## Old Answer:

Emojis range can be found [here](http://apps.timwhitlock.info/emoji/tables/unicode#block-6c-other-additional-symbols)

So, this would result in (not tested):

```
if(getTitle().substring(0,5)
    == ("/[\u2190-\u21FF] | [\u2600-\u26FF] | [\u2700-\u27BF] | 
          [\u3000-\u303F] | [\u1F300-\u1F64F] | [\u1F680-\u1F6FF]/g")){
    firstCharacter = getTitle().substring(0,5);
} else{
    firstCharacter = getTitle().substring(0,1);
}
```

Comment: That would get you in trouble if the emoji is not a simple one. For instance, for emojis that comprise modifiers (skin tones) / variation selectors (to switch between text/emoji presentation) / zwj sequences (families) / flags & such (you cannot predict the length of the emoji without actually parsing the codepoints) - see http://unicode.org/reports/tr51/ for reference.

Comment: @mrlem you are right. Android now has [EmojiCompat](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/text/emoji/EmojiCompat) and I updated my answer. :)

Comment: @yennsarah Indeed this makes our lives easier... except that the original issue was to get the first character (be it an emoji or not). For this, EmojiCompat is quite cumbersome as far as I know: it allows you to process the string a therefore have emojis being replaced with emojispans, but this is not directly solving the issue. -- you may also use BreakIterator.getCharacterInstance(), however if you use java.text version of the class it has various shortcomings in unicode support, and if you use icu's version it has compatibility issues -- quite a mess!

Answer (score 2):

Just use `String.codePointAt()`

```java
new String(Character.toChars(getTitle().codePointAt(0)))
```

Comment: OK but not perfect in case flag emoji 